# Integrate onenote with MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, onenote, onenote-api

I want integrate onenote desktop app with mvc application and i want to manage all the operation like add a new page and update existing page content and delete a page all with mvc application only. Is there any why to do this.

Now i have implemented an sample application mvc to integrate with onenote by doing oauth authentication.and i am getting my page content. and i am rendering that content into my browser.

But my question is that i want open an page from onenote in onenote editor from my application then what ever changes i made those changes will be reflect to the onenote desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

We have an ASP.NET sample in github. You can issue POST pages requests to add pages, and they will sync to all clients (as long as you have the notebook open)

Dev site for onenote api, post pages:

https://dev.onenote.com/docs#/reference/post-pages

ASP.NET sample:

https://github.com/OneNoteDev/OneNoteApiSampleAspNetCore